# Getting memory error "core dumped" while using Yolov8 in DSP-SLAM

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, slam, yolov8

I have replace the MaskRcnn modle of [DSP-SLAM](https://github.com/JingwenWang95/DSP-SLAM) with the yolov8 module and have rewritten the codes in the original repository. However, I keep getting a error "Aborted (core dumped)" when I run the yolo model together with DSP-SLAM.

This is the error I get:

```
DSP-SLAM: Object Oriented SLAM with Deep Shape Priors.

This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;

This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it

under certain conditions. See LICENSE.txt.



Input sensor was set to: Monocular



Loading ORB Vocabulary. This could take a while...

Vocabulary loaded!



/home/linux/GitClone/DSP-SLAM

Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.154  Python-3.8.17 torch-2.0.1 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti, 12001MiB)

Setup complete ✅ (24 CPUs, 31.2 GB RAM, 243.4/915.3 GB disk)

device used is  cuda:0



Camera Parameters: 

- fx: 930.166

- fy: 930.166

- cx: 480

- cy: 270

- k1: -0.147571

- k2: -0.0943432

- p1: 0

- p2: 0

- fps: 15

- color order: RGB (ignored if grayscale)



ORB Extractor Parameters: 

- Number of Features: 2000

- Scale Levels: 8

- Scale Factor: 1.2

- Initial Fast Threshold: 20

- Minimum Fast Threshold: 7



-------

Start processing sequence ...

Images in the sequence: 1943



New Map created with 158 points

New Keyframe

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'

  what():  RuntimeError: std::bad_alloc



At:

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/torch_utils.py(134): fuse_conv_and_bn

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/tasks.py(132): fuse

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/autobackend.py(103): __init__

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py(305): setup_model

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py(238): predict

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py(115): decorate_context

  /home/linux/anaconda3/envs/reconstruct_M/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py(98): __call__

  /home/linux/GitClone/DSP-SLAM/reconstruct/detector2d.py(120): make_prediction

  /home/linux/GitClone/DSP-SLAM/reconstruct/mono_sequence.py(79): get_detections

  /home/linux/GitClone/DSP-SLAM/reconstruct/mono_sequence.py(151): get_frame_by_id



Aborted (core dumped)
```

GPU=RTX4070 Ti, Cuda=11.8, torch = 2.0.1

yolov8 runs independently as illustrated on the official [documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/)

I have tried to change the size of the model from X to L to M to n but no difference.

Have restarted my computer multiple times. But doesn't work.

Have update Ultralytics package.

Have changed the frame rate per second.

This is my code:

```
class Detector2DY8(object):

    def __init__(self, configs):

        

        ultralytics.checks()

        

        config_weights = configs.Detector2DY8.weight_path

        self.yolo_model = YOLO(config_weights)

        self.yolo_model.to('cuda')

        print("device used is ",self.yolo_model.device)

        self.min_bb_area = configs.min_bb_area

        self.predictions = None

      



    def make_prediction(self, image, object_class="cars"):

        

        assert object_class == "chairs" or object_class == "cars"

        self.predictions = self.yolo_model(image)

        

        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(self.predictions[0].boxes.cls.tolist()) if x in object_class_table[object_class]]

        masks = []

        n_det = len(indices)

        

        boxes = [[self.predictions[0].boxes.xyxy.tolist()[i]] for i in indices]

        masks = [self.predictions[0].masks.data.tolist()[i] for i in indices]

        scores = [self.predictions[0].boxes.conf.tolist()[i] for i in indices]

        boxes = np.concatenate(boxes, axis=0)

        scores = np.stack(scores, axis=0)



        if n_det == 0:

            masks = np.zeros((0, 0, 0))

        else:

            masks = np.stack(masks,axis=0)

        assert boxes.shape[0] == masks.shape[0]

        

        return self.get_valid_detections(boxes, masks, scores)



    def visualize_result(self, image, filename):

        self.model.show_result(image, self.predictions, out_file=filename)



    def get_valid_detections(self, boxes, masks, scores):

        # Remove those on the margin

        cond1 = (boxes[:, 0] >= 30) & (boxes[:, 1] > 10) & (boxes[:, 2] < 1211) & (boxes[:, 3] < 366)

        boxes_area = (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0]) * (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1])

        # Remove those with too small bounding boxes

        cond2 = (boxes_area > self.min_bb_area)

        cond3 = (scores >= 0.70)



        valid_mask = (cond2 & cond3)

        valid_instances = {"pred_boxes": boxes[valid_mask, :4],

                           "pred_masks": masks[valid_mask, ...]}



        return valid_instances



    @staticmethod

    def save_masks(masks):

        mask_imgs = torch.tensor(masks).cpu().numpy()

        n = mask_imgs.shape[0]

        for i in range(n):

            cv2.imwrite("mask_%d.png" % i, mask_imgs[i, ...].astype(np.float32) * 255.)

``
```